# Referencing static objects created in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to create some design-time data using XAML. I am afraid I can't find guidance on the Web on how to create an array by referencing other XAML-created objects. Something similar to this...

```xml
<MyClass x:Key="Obj1" Prop1="..." Prop2="..." />
<MyClass x:Key="Obj2" Prop1="..." Prop2="..." />
<x:Array Type={x:Type my:MyClass} x:Key="MyObjects">
  <StaticResource Key="Obj1" />
  <StaticResource Key="Obj2" />
</x:Array>
```

Unfortunately, the above doesn't work. Is there something that would work?

I reproduced the error by creating an empty Xamarin Forms app with the latest VS Studio for the Mac. I added this to `ContentPage.Resources`...

```xml
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <n:String x:Key="myString">Hello World</n:String>
            <x:Array x:Key="myArray" Type="{x:Type n:String}">
                <StaticResource Key="myString" />
            </x:Array>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

I get the following error at the start of the application:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException
... StaticResource not found for key myString
```

I am building a Xamarin.Forms application using the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac.

Also, I am aware I can create the objects as direct children of the array. I am trying to create them separately so that I can include them in different collections.

*Update* (after the suggestion from @junior-jiang-msft)

I tried Junior Jiang's proposal but I get the following build error...

```
/Users/savasp/Projects/test/test/MainPage.xaml: Error: The given key 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName' was not present in the dictionary.
```

Here's the sample XAML Form in a new, vanilla Xamarin.Forms project...

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="test.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="m1">hello</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="m2">world</x:String>
        <x:Array x:Key="array" Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <Setter Value="{StaticResource m1}" />
            <Setter Value="{StaticResource m2}" />
        </x:Array>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource array}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand something about `ResourceDictionary`.For the value and assignment of `StaticResource`, please refer to this document.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#creating-and-consuming-a-resourcedictionary

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstand something about `ResourceDictionary`.For the value and assignment of `StaticResource`.

```
<ContentPage...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="myStringOne">Hello String One</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="myStringTwo">Hello String Two</x:String>
        <x:Array x:Key="myArray" Type="{x:Type x:String}">
          <x:String>mono</x:String>
          <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
          <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
          <x:String>monorail</x:String>
          <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
          <x:String>monotone</x:String>
          <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
          <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
          <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
      </x:Array>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
   
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemSource="{StaticResource myArray}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

You can refer to this document [Creating and Consuming a ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#creating-and-consuming-a-resourcedictionary).

Comment: Thank you @junior-jiang-msft. Unfortunately your proposal doesn't work either. I updated my question with what I tried based on your response.

Comment: @SavasParastatidis Thanks for replying , I will check it.If good news will share here. :)

Comment: @SavasParastatidis I have updated answer.Listview's itemsource can not directly use Resource .You need to convert them.If not just can can sample show data as answer. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91200/binding-into-datatemplate-viewcell

Comment: Thank you @junior-jiang-msft. Yes, I already know how to do the data binding, both at runtime and at design time, using the StaticResource extension class. That wasn't my question. My question was about reusing Resource Dictionary entries as members of an array.

Anyway... I have moved on from this. I had to replicate the sample data for design-time data binding. It works, it's just not as tidy as i would have liked.

Comment: @SavasParastatidis Okey, if be helpful , thanks for marking it . And if other good ideas will share here later. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare like this:

```
  <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Hello</x:String>
            <x:String>World</x:String>
        </x:Array>
```

Or, another example using Color Object:

```
 <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type Color}">
                <Color>Aqua</Color>
                <Color>Black</Color>
                <Color>Blue</Color>
                <Color>Fuchsia</Color>
                <Color>Gray</Color>
                <Color>Green</Color>
                <Color>Lime</Color>
                <Color>Maroon</Color>
                <Color>Navy</Color>
                <Color>Olive</Color>
                <Color>Pink</Color>
                <Color>Purple</Color>
                <Color>Red</Color>
                <Color>Silver</Color>
                <Color>Teal</Color>
                <Color>White</Color>
                <Color>Yellow</Color>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
```

You can check the XAML Markup docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#array)

Comment: I am sorry. My bad. I should have mentioned that I knew about declaring them as per the examples in the page you linked.

I am trying to declare objects so that I can reference them directly but also add them as members of different collections.